# Headless Browser C# and Alternatives

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

currently I have the following code using selenium and phantomjs in c#:

```
public class Driver
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.website.com/");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.website.com/productpage/");
            driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('pdp_selectedSize').value = '10.0'");  //FindElementById("pdp_selectedSize").SendKeys("10.0");
            driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('product_form').submit()");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.website/cart/");
            Screenshot sh = driver.GetScreenshot();
            sh.SaveAsFile(@"C:\temp\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

My objective is to be able to add a product to my cart and then checkout automatically.  The screenshot is just included to test whether the code was successfully working.  My first issue is that I often get an error that it cannot find the element with product id "pdp_selectedSize". I'm assuming this is because the the webdriver hasn't loaded the page yet, so I'm looking for a way to keep checking until it finds it without having to set a specific timeout.

I'm also looking for faster alternatives to use instead of a headless browser.  I used a headless browser instead of http requests because I need certain cookies to be able to checkout on the page, and these cookies are set through javascript within the page. If anyone has a reccommendation for a faster method, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `ExpectedConditions` in the [Selenium Reference](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: Is that part of WebDriverWait?

Comment: It works in conjunction with `WebDriverWait`, yes.

Comment: Thank you I got that part to work. Could you help me at all with my second question?

Comment: You are welcome.  As to your second question, any answer I could give you would be _completely_ subjective and likely of no real value to you.  That being said, I found this [article](https://watirmelon.blog/2015/12/08/real-vs-headless-browsers-for-automated-acceptance-tests/) to be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, it would behoove you to look into using `ExpectedConditions' which is part of the`WebDriverWait`class in`Selenium`.  The following code sample was taken from here and only serves as a reference point.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
{
   driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
   d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")));
}
```

More on `WebDriverWaits` [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/).

As to your second question, that is a really subjective thing, in my opinion.  Headless Browsers aren't necessarily any faster or slower than a real browser.  See this [article](https://watirmelon.blog/2015/12/08/real-vs-headless-browsers-for-automated-acceptance-tests/).

Comment: Is there anything that works with the WebRequest class to process javascript?

Comment: That I am not 100% sure on.  'Selenium' does have a 'JSExecutor' class though.